# Determine the necessary values of v and i in the circuit

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

[image]
Determine the necessary values of v and i in the circuit.
I want to know the working out of this problem please.

[image]

Comment: To get help, show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the add up all the resistors, and that's where I'm struggling.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: I have the answer for this question, but there is no working out. I started of adding all the resistors and in hopes of I could get the voltage using ohm's law with the 1A current. but it was wrong and I think the problem is from adding all the resistors.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for adding your work. That lets us help you figure out where you went wrong.

In this case, your calculation of the overall resistance is correct, but unfortunately, this doesn't help you find the total voltage and total current. The 1 A current that's given is **not** the current through the entire circuit, but rather only the current through the 1 Ω resistor.

Therefore, start with what you do know, and work up from there.

- There's 1 A of current flowing through the 1 Ω resistor. Ohm's Law tells you what the voltage across that resistor must be.
- The 2 Ω resistor is in parallel with the 1 Ω resistor; therefore, it has the same voltage across it. What does Ohm's Law tell you about the current flowing through it?
- The total of those two currents must be flowing through the 3 Ω resistor. And so forth, and so on ...